# segmentation fault error in training caffe based convolutional neural network model

Tags: segmentation-fault, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am following a [tutorial](http://xiaoyongshen.me/webpage_portrait/index.html) for human segmentation, in which a `FCN-8s` `caffe` model is trained for semantic segmentation problem using Pascal VOC-12 dataset in which out of 21 classes, one class is of person, and on top of it they have again trained the similar model but for 1 class, which is human in portrait mode, and images in training database is of 800 X 600 size.
But when i tried it to train for landscape mode images of human of size 360 X 640, i am getting segmentation fault error while setting up fc6 convolutional layer, error log is in the below link as its too big to post it here.
[error log](https://pastebin.com/t3vi1qk9)

[training script:](https://pastebin.com/nnhM38eg)

[protobuf file for FCN-8s model:](https://pastebin.com/yFhxV2kk)

[solver file for model used on top of FCN-8s:](https://pastebin.com/NvjUrD6R)

[train protobuf file for model used on top of FCN-8:](https://pastebin.com/nyej9ZUd)

Comment: what is `"ImageMat"` input layer? you might get the segfault there.

Comment: I don,t know much about this, i am new to caffe and CNN, Actually some additional layers type has been defined by author of tutorial in caffe model, i am sharing the definition of that layer: pastebin.com/HfPzm7Ej , And for the same layer type, it is working when i use dataset of 800 by 600 size images(which is also used by author)